# Moving a JTable inside a forum

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Im trying to have JTable displayed on my forum, but i want a top row to be a "menu" with a row of buttons. I tried multiple things to get this to work, but i cant get the JTable to shift downwards. The parts i have commented out are things ive been playing around with.

```
Table1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        Table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        Table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(Table1);   
        add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setLocation(0,300);
    Container TopMenu = getContentPane();
    SpringLayout TopMenuLayout = new SpringLayout();
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, project1, 325, SpringLayout.WEST, TopMenu);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, project1, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, TopMenu);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, project2, 100, SpringLayout.WEST, project1);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, project2, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, TopMenu);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, project3, 100, SpringLayout.WEST, project2);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, project3, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, TopMenu);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, project4, 100, SpringLayout.WEST, project3);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, project4, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, TopMenu);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, project5, 100, SpringLayout.WEST, project4);
        TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, project5, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, TopMenu);
        //TopMenuLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, Table1, 150, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    TopMenu.setLayout(TopMenuLayout);
        //TopMenu.add(scrollPane);
        TopMenu.add(project1);
        //TopMenu.add(Table1);
        TopMenu.add(project2);
        TopMenu.add(project3);
        TopMenu.add(project4);
        TopMenu.add(project5);
```

Comment: Use a BorderLayout, for the main container and add the top menu JPanel BorderLayout.PAGE_START, and the JScrollPane with your JTable BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: some painting will hepl to potential answerer(s) - Moving a JTable inside a forum and v.s. tried multiple things to get this to work, but i cant get the JTable to shift downwards :-)

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for Swing JComponents in local variables

Comment: Thanks both of you, i will try the borderlayout mentioned and see if it works out.

Comment: @mKorbel Im not sure what an SSCCE/MCVE is :(

Comment: @user2826539 [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @user2826539 don't to mix `setLocation` with `LayoutManager`,

Comment: `Im not sure what an SSCCE/MCVE is` - did you search the forum or the internet? Its amazing what you can find. This is basic problem solving.

Comment: Ive tried the BorderLayout and added my JPanel and JScrollPane, but still no use...  I added them like this:
 Container.add(TopMenu, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
Container.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: Did you first set the layout manager of the container to BorderLayout? This won't work without doing this first. More importantly, consider reading the layout manager tutorial docs.

Comment: I did set the Main container's layout to BorderLayout. Ill look into that